# Solve for $x$ in an system of a linear and logarithmic equation.

Tags: logarithms, systems-of-equations

I have this question on my homework: $$\\f(x)=\ln{(x-3)}\\g(x)=\frac12x-7\\\text{solve for x in:}f(x)=g(x)$$

I have used the substitution property to get this: $$\ln{(x-3)}=\frac12x-7$$.

I don't know how to solve for $x$ from here. Any level of math is ok, I just need to figure out how to solve it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no solution you can write down as x= some formula not involving x. Depending on maths level, you could try graphing f and g and see where they cross or use a numerical solution method e.g. Newton's Method or Bisection.

Answer (score 1):

From the graph below, two solutions can be roughly approximated : $x\simeq 3$ and $x\simeq 19.5$

Various methods of numerical calculus leads to better approximates : $x\simeq 3.004095$ and $x\simeq 19.6214$

For lovers of special functions : See below the analytical solution, thanks to the Lambert W function, which is a multivaluated function.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Consider the function
$$
h(x)=f(x)-g(x)=\ln(x-3)-\frac{x}{2}+7
$$
Then $\lim_{x\to3}h(x)=-\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty}h(x)=-\infty$. Moreover
$$
h'(x)=\frac{1}{x-3}-\frac{1}{2}=\frac{5-x}{x-3}
$$
so $h$ has a maximum for $x=5$. Now
$$
h(5)=\ln2-\frac{5}{2}+7=\ln2+\frac{9}{2}>0
$$
So the equation has two solutions by the intermediate value theorem applied to the intervals $(3,5]$ and $[5,\infty)$.

The solutions can be approximated with several numeric methods.